# System.OutOfMemoryException when rebuilding solution with three SSIS projects

Tags: ssis, out-of-memory, visual-studio-2019, rebuild

I am using Visual Studio 2019. I have three SSIS projects in my solution. in all my projects I have about 400 packages. When I want to rebuild my Solution I have below Error :

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
at 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSManagedXmlSerializationHelper.GetXmlDocumentOuterXml(XmlDocument 
doc, Boolean indent)
at 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSManagedXmlSerializationHelper.AfterSavePackageToXML(IDTSPackage100 
package, IDTSInfoEvents100 events, String& packageXml)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackagePersist100.ClonePackageToXML(Object& 
pvDestination, Boolean vbReturnDOM, IDTSEvents100 pEvents)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.SavePackage(IProjectStorage storage, Package package, 
String streamName, Boolean preserveVersionGuid)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.SavePackage(Package package, String streamName, Boolean 
preserveVersionGuid)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughOb j(IOutputWindow outputWindow)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow outputWindow)          0
```

If I rebuild one project at a time, It is ok. But rebuild solution does not work. When I want to deploy one of the project sometimes my visual studio is crashed and closed.

Before I was using Visual Studio 2017 and I did not have those problem. Do you have any Idea?

**EDIT 1**: I have 16G RAM and when I have those errors I have more than 6 GB free RAM

**EDIT 2** : This is my VS 2019

[image]

**Edit 3** : [image]

**Edit 4 :** I use CozyRoc components

Comment: Does your system actually have enough free memory? Or are you physically resource constrained?

Comment: i have 16G RAM and when I have those errors I have more than 6 GB free RAM

Comment: Have you tried building a project at a time? If so, does that work?

Comment: Yes I tried that. I have written in my question. If i rebuild one project at a time, most of times, it works. But I have still Deploying problem.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the .vs file, restarting, and running a rebuild?  Try a clean if it is available.

Comment: @salli : even after rebooting windows i have still this problem

Comment: I would recommend turning on delayvalidation property for the packages.  With 400 packages I am not sure the best way to implement this attempt.  From earlier comment ".vs" is a hidden file in the solution directory.  Regardless of the reboot, you should try to see if deleting it would help.

Comment: @sali i will let you know about reasult